# htaccess redirect to SSL not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl-certificate

I used the following code in htaccess to redirect my inner page urls to https:// but they are not working. When i go to my home page it redirects to https and then all inner pages do the same but if I access any inner page without using the secure url it doesn't redirect to secured.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody pls help?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite conditions are too restrictive to match every possible wordpress URI.  You might try redirecting based on server port instead.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response, but it didn't work. Do you think I should remove the index.php related code? Because then the redirection works but inner pages show 404 error though the url is secured.

Comment: Yes, I would say move the server port conditions to the top of the htaccess file and/or omit the other rules and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say try WP Force SSL plugin. I've used this in the past to avoid making changes to my .htaccess file.